# Multiple Certificates in DER encoded format in a single file

Tags: x509certificate, der

Can a single file contain multiple DER encoded certificates. I have seen CA bundle file, which is in PEM format (containing multiple BEGIN and END), but is the same possible for DER encoded certs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can concatenate multiple DER files, but the result won't be readable by any software except yours.

If you need multiple certificates in binary form for whatever reason, there exists PKCS#7 format in which you can store multiple certificates without private keys. Then you can use PKCS#12 for storing multiple certificates, encrypted and optionally with private keys.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am new to this area. Can a PKCS#7 format be DER encoded? I have a requirement (from a specification) which says that I have to download and use a file which contains multiple X509 certificates. The file will be  DER encoded. Does that mean that the format will be PKCS?

Comment: Each certificate is DER-encoded initially. *Then* it can be placed to some container, be it PKCS7, PKCS12 or whatever else. Or it can be encoded again with Base64 and then stored in some container. So from what you describe it's not possible to conclude, in what final format the certificates will be.